# Storing and retrieving checkbox selected items in WP7 Local Database using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have 105 listbox items with checkboxes. When user selects the items, i want the selected items to be stored in WP7 Local Database. So, do I need to enter all the list items in the database table column? Or is there any other way to store it and display the selected items when required? I am using C# and XAML. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call me a simpleton but this is how i do it

```
// to display user selection - days is a List<DayOfWeek> as stored by you in database
foreach(var day in days)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = day.ToString();

    lbi.Content = tb;
    lbi.VerticalContentAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
    lbi.IsSelected = AlarmMod.AlarmData.SelectedDays.Contains(day);

    this.listBox.Items.Add(lbi);
}

// to store
List<DayOfWeek> iDays = new List<DayOfWeek>();

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if ((this.listBox.Items[i] as ListBoxItem).IsSelected)
    {
        iDays.Add((DayOfWeek)i);
    }
}
// now you store iDays which is a List<DayOfWeek> in database.
```

Comment: Do you know how to store / retrieve List<> in database ? i use a List<DayOfWeek> in above example.

Comment: No, I have no idea about storing list<> in database. In your above example, the List<DayOfWeek> is a column in the database, right.

Comment: How to declare List<Checkbox> object as table column in local database? Please help!

Comment: why not just have a list of bit / boolean values?

Comment: I am not able to get you. Can you please explain?

Comment: How are you going to store idays in Local DB?

Comment: how about a simple comman seperated list ? you join days to user selection to store "monday,tuesday,friday" and use string.split to split them into individual items

Answer (score 0):

You could store only the checked items in a database table and if you need them again just display your whole list and check the items which exist in your database.

Or you could store all items in the database with a IsChecked Field and then you could simply read the whole table in a list and then bind the Checkbox to the IsChecked Field.

Comment: how can I get the checkbox checked items in database table? please be elaborate...thanks

Comment: You go through your CheckBox-es with a foreach loop and if it is checked then you add it to the database.